# Expo + Firebase - Handle app package name in separated dev and prod app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, expo

I have two separated Firebase projects, one for dev and other for prod environment.
I'm trying to add my Expo app to the dev project but I cannot add the same app package in two different projects.

How to handle app package name in both projects? Should I use env variables inside expo to change the package name?

Also, when I upload my app to stores for internal tests and publishing, will I have to build the app two times? one for dev and one for final prod version?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone else ends up with same question:

In your `package.json` create a script with a `APP_VARIANT` (or any other name) env variable:

```
"android|ios_dev": "APP_VARIANT=development expo prebuild --clean && expo run:android|ios --device",
"android|ios_prod": "APP_VARIANT=production expo prebuild --clean && expo run:android|ios --device"
```

Now inside your `app.config.js` you just need to follow expo [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variants/) to get your app switching `package name`.

It's important to perform a [clean prebuild](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/#clean) if `APP_VARIANT` value is different than the one you're working on before because expo will recreate all project files based on the new `package name` provided by `app.config.js`. Withoud doing this you'll get some errors.

Answer (score -2):

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Notes Guru",
    "slug": "notes-guru",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/logo.jpg",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/logo_mini.png"
    },
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/template.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "icon": "./assets/logo.jpg",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSRemindersUsageDescription": "This app uses the calendar"
      },
      "associatedDomains": [
        "applinks:test.page.link"
      ],
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.jk0712.7Search-ppc-advertiser"
    },
    "android": {
      ***"package": "[notesguru.org][1]",***
      "versionCode": 2,
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/logo.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/logo.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "d7e815f1-ef5f-4834-bd4b-69ad85f633e5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```